# Scala empty class,object,traits

Tags: scala

I want to learn scala language.
In many documents or video tutorials, I see scala developers create empty class or objects and use that on another class as parameter or implement empty traits !
for example :

```
object Controller {
  sealed trait Controller
  case object Login extends Controller
  case object Logout extends Controller
}
```

Or this :

```
sealed trait Expression
case class Number(num: Int) extends Expression
case class Plus(a: Expression, b: Expression) extends Expression
case class Minus(a: Expression, b: Expression) extends Expression

object ExpressionEvaluate {
  def value(expression: Expression): Int = expression match {
    case Number(value) => value
    case Plus(a, b) => value(a) + value(b)
    case Minus(a, b) => value(a) - value(b)
  }
}
```

I want to know what is this pattern ?
What is meaning empty class ,Object or traits ?
Why developers use this pattern ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This pattern:

```
sealed trait Controller
case object Login extends Controller
case object Logout extends Controller
```

Or this

```
sealed trait Expression
case class Number(num: Int) extends Expression
case class Plus(a: Expression, b: Expression) extends Expression
case class Minus(a: Expression, b: Expression) extends Expression
```

Are known as [algebraic data types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type). They are the Scala way of creating a [co-product/sum types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_union) (also known as a tagged union). When you receive a trait of type `Expression` in your signature, you know that you will receive one of the concrete implementations. The way you discover which type is the concrete type is via [pattern matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pattern_matching), which is the ability to match on types. More so, the compiler is smart enough with a `sealed trait` to know all its underlying concrete types and let you know in case your pattern match isn't exhaustive, for example, if I add a `Divide` type:

```
case class Divide(a: Expression, b: Expression) extends Expression
```

And compile, the compiler will complain:

```
Warning:(18, 48) match may not be exhaustive.
It would fail on the following input: Divide(_, _)
      def value(expression: Expression): Int = expression match {
```

As for the "empty classes", we have to distinguish between two types. One is a `case class`. A case class is a way of creating immutable record types in Scala, think of them as a [product type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_type) on steroids. These are classes in which the compiler automatically derives an implementation of `hashCode` and `equals`, and also adds methods which provide us syntax sugar when we pattern match via `apply`/`unapply`. For example:

```
case Number(value) => value
```

You see that we are able to access the `value` field on `Number` in the pattern match, how is that possible? It is possible because the compiler provides us an `unapply` method which is used to deconstruct the case class.

The other one is a `case object`, which is a way of creating a [singleton type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_(mathematics)) (a type which represents exactly one value) in Scala. Since we don't have any fields on `Login` or `Logout`, we can create a single representation of that type.